# When i add image into container i can`t make it responsive

Tags: html, css, image, height

I have a dilemma with some code in HTML & CSS, when I add a simple header with an image and I set properties to image {height:100%;
                                          width: auto;} it works, but when I have the image in more complex code isn`t working anymore.
In the smaller code if i change height of header the images change as well,but on second code if i change height of header image stays on same size
Can someone please explain to me why that happens?

Down here i have two code snippets to see what I`m saying

```css
header{
  height:80px;
  background:#eee;
}
.header-content{
  display:flex;
}
.header-content img{
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
.links-list{
  display:flex;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.links-list li{
  margin-right:4rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- !Header -->
  <header class="header ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-content">
<img src="http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/logo1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="menu-links">
          <ul class="links-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
       
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

```css
nav{
  background:#eee;
  height:80px;
}
nav img{
  height:100%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<img src="http://www.lazarangelov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/logo1.jpg" alt="">
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by _"isn't working anymore"_?

Comment: You have already set the header height to 80px, so you can set the image height 80px also, you need to use % only when the container's (header) height is changing.

Comment: I edited the post and i explained more want i`m trying to say

Comment: #Hassan Thamery can you please explain more why if is in the container cannot give 100% height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the codepen link for reference: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pmEgaM

you just need to keep the styling for header as height: 100%; and keep changing height of image in the header-content img styling this will give you expected result

```
header{
  height: 100%;  # this will make sure your header height is 100% irrespective of image geight
  background:#eee;
}
.header-content img{
  height:100%;   #this height you can change 
  width:auto;
}
```